# if value is equal to either a or b. shorthand?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, short

Yea some javascript shorthand.
if that value is equal to the value of a or b, maybe something like this?

```
if(val==a||b)
```

Comment: or just `val === a || val === b`.

Comment: There is no magic way, especially if you _don't want any arrays_.

Comment: The _shortest_ way possible could be `if([a,b].include(val))`.

Comment: The short version is: There is no shorthand, no. `if (val == a || val == b)` is as short as it gets without adding arrays or sets or calls to helper functions.